# AppCmd: Framework vs Framework64

Tags: 64-bit, appcmd, machine.config

I have a batch of new server getting installed and I'm finally trying to automate as much of at process as possible. Part of that includes making some changes to machine.config, like setting configSource on connectionStrings and setting the machine keys across a lb pool.

It appears that on a 64bit os, appcmd only effects the config in the Framework64 directory, which is fine until you have a 32bit app running. I need to change the config in both the Framework and the Framework64 directories. Is there a secret argument (like /commit:MACHINE32 or something) that you can use to tell appcmd which config to mess with?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is both easy, amusing and depressing. :-)

I keep forgetting that on 64bit Windows, `System32` is 64bit, and `SysWow64` is the 32bit only apps for the system.

So, `System32\inetsrv\appcmd` works with the Framework64 files, and `SysWow64\inetsrv\appcmd` works with the Framework files.

Run the same command in both to update both framework config files, at least for APPHOST and WEBROOT and MACHINE commit paths.